# Shipping Rates vs shipping methods

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-rates

I have a Magento 2.4.5 shop with 3 shipping methods.
I want to give same price to all, but this price will depend on customer shipping zip code.
One price for a set of zip code (SET A), and other price for other set (SET B).
Now, if Order total is bigger than 40,00€, SET A, will have free shipping, and if Order total is bigger than 80,00€, SET B will have a free shipping.

My question is: Can I do this shipping rates csv file? Or do I need to code or install extra module?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess simply you can go with the custom extension development or use any available extensions from Magento marketplace because your request clearly a custom request. Magento do have inbuilt table rates shipping carrier but it is not going to fulfill all your requirements.

May be this Amasty extension can do everything for you:
https://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates-for-magento-2.html

And the shipping restriction extension combination will also help you to go more specific solution.
https://amasty.com/shipping-restrictions-for-magento-2.html